# Software license conditioned on company size or revenue

Tags: software, licensing

A software license might be different if the company where the software is being used is larger or smaller. So if Joey is an independent freelance contractor with his own company with revenue less than the limit and working for the giant multinational billion dollar revenue company, is it the smaller or the larger revenue that counts towards the licensing? Typical examples are Docker and Unity, where license and cost depends on where the usage is.

Comment: Do you have a specific license in mind?  The terms and definitions would very likely be spelled out there.

Comment: @jwh20 Examples are Docker and Unity Engine. From Unity it's simply "Does you company have more than 100 000K USD in revenue?" and from Docker it's similar but they have the word "in use" which is open for interpretation. Have a smaller company use it and sell the result to the larger, then the larger is not directly using the build tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will depend first and foremost on the terms of the license. There appears to be no direct violation of a law - businesses have great freedom to set prices. For some special goods like food, governments may have price controls that limit tis freedom, but software licenses are generally not is such categories.

The most common exception to this would probably be [(F)RAND licensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reasonable_and_non-discriminatory_licensing) - (fair, )  reasonable, and **non-discriminatory**. This is typically not a direct legal restriction, but one that follows from common technical standards processes such as ISO. Companies that submit patented technologies for standardization commonly agree to non-discriminatory pricing